# Google+ and SEO: +1 button or follow button / profile badge on a new website?

Tags: seo, google-plus, google-plus-one, social-sharing-buttons, google-plus-pages

I am starting a new website, and I expect only to have few daily visitors for the first month.

I know how +1s on the different pages could help the rank of that specific page in Google search. but we also know that [each follower to the Google+ page also counts as a +1 for the linked homepage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/46418/24366).

Considering the age of website and its few visitors, I wonder if I should include a [+1 button](http://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) on each page, or if it would be better to include a [profile badge](https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/) or [follow button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/) on each page and focus all the benefit on the homepage and Google+ page?

I know I could use all buttons and badge together, but I don't want to confuse the visitors with too many options.

**In other words, for a new website, is it enough to only make the homepage popular on Google, or should we do this for all pages from the beginning?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any evidence that social signals give your site enough traction to make implementation of the +1 button worth it from an SEO perspective.  If you are hoping for viral growth driven by sharing on social networks, then a +1 button (and facebook like button) should be a number one priority.

You should create pages for your site on each of the social networks:

- It prevents squatters coming along and doing it before you get to it
- Those pages often appear in the search results for your brand name -- its nice to have sites you control monopolizing the first page.